# How can i logout a jsp page after 3 minutes if its inactive for 3 minutes?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to log out my Jsp page automatically after 3 minutes if the page page is inactive for 3 minutes.can u help me through java script?

I tried like this,

```
enter code here
function change() {
    try{
        if(readCookie("hs_lefttime") != "") {
            lefttime=readCookie("hs_lefttime"); 
        } 
    } catch(e){}
    if((Number(lefttime)+3*60*1000)<=(new Date().getTime())) {
        logOutSession.load();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. As soon as you show what you're already tried and provide some ideas for what you think could work, as well as anything you've researched.

Comment: i have use the following script in my jsp page..

Comment: function change()
{
    try{
     if(readCookie("hs_lefttime") != "")
     {
       lefttime=readCookie("hs_lefttime");
     }
      }
    catch(e){}      
    if((Number(lefttime)+3*60*1000)<=(new Date().getTime()))
 {

     logOutSession.load();
 }

Comment: but in some cases it auto logout within 20s

Answer (score 0):

set session timeout on your webserver

Comment: i had already set the session time out in my web.xml
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>3</session-timeout> 
 </session-config>

Answer (score -2):

```
var timer = null;
function auto_reload()
{
    window.location = 'http://domain.com/page.php';
}
```

and in tab body of html, you write :

```
<body onload="timer = setTimeout('auto_reload()',180000);">
```

Edit : THIS IS ONLY RUN IN SINGLE TAB.

Comment: is this working fine when i open my web site in two tabs and keeping one tab idle and the second one as active?

Comment: can u please give a suggestion to work this javascript for auto logout for mutiple tabs.As this is worling fine only for single tab

Comment: function checkActivity(timeout, interval, elapsed) {
    if ($.active) {
        elapsed = 0;
        $.active = false;
        $.get('heartbeat');
    }
    if (elapsed < timeout) {
        elapsed += interval;
        setTimeout(function() {
            checkActivity(timeout, interval, elapsed);
        }, interval);
    } else {
     logOutSession.load();// Redirect to "session expired" page.
    }
}

Comment: < is this working fine when i open my web site in two tabs and keeping one tab idle and the second one as active? > JS only run in client. If you open 2 tabs, and keeping one tab idle, you need process in server (by Ajax). Get the last time when user active in the ( another ) page, and input its to database ( temp ). so, you need compare the current time in the client and calculating with getted time in server. That is my idea.